# Squid add LAN IP, squid username and squid port in query when using url_rewrite_program

Tags: rewrite, squid, url

I use squid as transparent proxy with SSL Bump interception.

Squid HTTP and HTTPS ports configuration are :

```
http_port 3127 transparent
https_port 3129 intercept ssl-bump generate-host-certificates=on cert=/opt/squid/ssl_cert/cert.crt key=/opt/squid/ssl_cert/cert.key options=NO_SSLv2,NO_SSLv3
```

I wrote the following URL program to force safe search for Google and duckduckgo :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use URI::URL;

# Turn off buffering to STDOUT
$| = 1;

# Read from STDIN
while (<STDIN>) {
    # Do some trimming
    s/^\s*//;
    s/\s*$//;

        my $string = $_;

    # Google Safe search
        if ($string =~ m/^http(s?)\:\/\/([a-z]+\.)?google\.([a-z]{2,3})(\.[a-z]{2,3})?\/.*(\?(as_)?q=)|(\#(as_)?q=)|(\&(as_)?q=)/) {
                #print "OK rewrite-url=\"$string", "&safe=active\"";
                if ($string !~ m/&safe=active/) {
                        print "OK url=\"$string", "&safe=active\"";
                        print "\n";
                } else {
                        print "OK\n";
                }
        }

        # Duckduckgo safe search
        elsif ($string =~ m/^http(s?)\:\/\/([a-z]+\.)?duckduckgo\.([a-z]{2,3})(\.[a-z]{2,3})?/) {
                #print "OK rewrite-url=\"$string", "&kp=1\"";
                if ($string !~ m/&kp=1/) {
                        print "OK url=\"$string", "&kp=1\"";
                        print "\n";
                } else {
                        print "OK\n";
                }
        }

        # If no one match, url still intact
        else {
                print "ERR\n";
        }
}
```

In squid configuration I add the following line :

```
url_rewrite_program /opt/squid/bin/url_rewriter
```

url_rewriter rewrite URL well when testing in CLI :

```
./url_rewriter
https://www.google.fr/?q=test
OK url="https://www.google.fr/?q=test&safe=active"
https://www.duckduckgo.com/
OK url="https://www.duckduckgo.com/&kp=1"
```

It works perfect in browser except that squid always add LAN IP, user name and squid port in the query. For example, it add this in the Query :

```
"%20192.168.1.18/192.168.1.18%20benoit%20GET%20myip=-%20myport=3129"
```

For google I get this :

```
https://www.google.fr/?q=test%20192.168.1.18/192.168.1.18%20benoit%20GET%20myip=-%20myport=3129&safe=active
```

instead of :

```
https://www.google.fr/?q=test&safe=active
```

For duckduckgo, I get

```
https://duckduckgo.com/%20192.168.1.18/192.168.1.18%20benoit%20GET%20myip=-%20myport=3127&kp=1
```

instead of :

```
https://duckduckgo.com/&kp=1
```

Why do I have this behavior ? Did I miss something ? 
I can post more configuration if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself.

Yes, I missed to give version of Squid and it was an important information in my case. I use Version 3.5.20

There is a new directive named **url_rewrite_extras** from squid 3.5

http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/url_rewrite_extras/

By default it add : **"%>a/%>A %un %>rm myip=%la myport=%lp"** in every query when using URL-rewriter/redirector helper program.

So I add the option to overwrite this value. I had to set a space as value because **url_rewrite_extras ""** add a dash "-" to query.

```
url_rewrite_extras " "
url_rewrite_program /opt/squid/bin/url_rewriter
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you missed a tiny detail. Squid doesn't add the myip= etc. stuff later, but before it sends the url to your rewriter. That means you have to remove it before you hand it back to squid.

Not all versions of squid do so, but it's documented up to version 3.4

TomTomTom